# How to correctly evaluate model performance of a regressor in GridSearchCV sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to found a set of best hyperparameters for my Gradient Boosting Regressor with Grid Search CV. But I have difficulties getting the performance of the best model.

My code is as follows, this function is expected to return an optimized model.

```
def parameter_tuning_Gradient_Boost(X,
                                    y,
                                    ):

    model = GradientBoostingRegressor()

    param_grid = {  'learning_rate': [0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1],
                    'subsample'    : [1.0, 0.8, 0.6],
                    'n_estimators' : [100, 200, 500, 1000],
                    'max_depth'    : [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
                    }

    grid_search = GridSearchCV( model,
                                param_grid,
                                cv = 5,
                                n_jobs = 8,
                                verbose = 0)

    grid_search.fit(X = X,
                    y = y,)

    print('Best Parameters by Searching: %s' % grid_search.best_params_)

    best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()

    model = GradientBoostingRegressor(  learning_rate = best_parameters['learning_rate'],
                                        subsample = best_parameters['subsample'],
                                        n_estimators = best_parameters['n_estimators'],
                                        max_depth = best_parameters['max_depth'],
                                        )
    
    return model
```

In general, I have the following questions：

1. Do I have to use `train_test_split` function to split X and y, and then feed `X_train` and `y_train` to `grid_search.fit` function? Some said `GridSearchCV` will automatically split data into train and test if you set cv = 5. But I saw some online tutorial will do something like this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

2. What is the metrics score for a regressor in GridSearchCV? after fitting GridSearchCV, I run the follwing commands and get way different score. I am wondering what is the correct way to get model cv perforamce for a regressor in GridSearchCV sklearn.

```
print("Best Score:", grid_search.score(X, y))
print("Best Score: %.3f" % grid_search.best_score_)
```

I tried to apply GridSearchCV method to perform parameter tuning for a regressor and get its cross-validation performance, I want to know what is the default evaluation metrics here, and I want to know do I have to split the data into train and test set when I set cv parameter in GridSearchCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes `GridSearchCV` will split the data into 5 train/test splits. It will then use these splits to find the optimal hyperparameters. However, it's also good practice to set aside a completely unseen split of the data. That you score the model(s) on when you are completely done with training. Take a look at [this](https://www.v7labs.com/blog/train-validation-test-set) article to read more on this. Remember, after evaluating the model on the unseen data set. You are not "allowed" to improve your model.
2. The scoring metric for `GridSearchCV` [can be user defined](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#gridsearch-scoring). But as a standard it will use the `scoring` parameter from the estimator. In this case `squared_error` which is the default scoring for [`GradientBoostingRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html), the parameter is named `loss=squared_error`.

To answer the second part of the question, we need to understand what happens in `GridSearchCV` when fitting. When the optimal hyperparameters are found, a model is refitted on all the data with the optimal hyperparameters, if `refit=True`, which it is by default.

`grid_search.score(X,y)` scores the refitted model on all of the data while

`grid_search._best_score` returns the **average** score of the models with the optimal hyperparameters on the five splits.

Comment: I specified scoring = 'r2' when initiate GridSearchCV, but after applying "grid_search.score(X,y)" and "grid_search.best_score_", they give me way different score, one is about 0.8 and one is about 0.28. I am wondering if they used different metrics for my regressor? or just "grid_search.score(X,y)" giving me a overfitting score?